# Disable Lightning Combobox in LWC based on FLS

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, documentation, fls

I know there is a way to check if the object/field is updateable, then only it will allow the user to read or update the field like below apex :

```
if(!Schema.SObjectType.Account.fields.Type.isUpdateable()) {
   //Fields Accessibility
   ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Error: Insufficient Access'));
   return null;
  }
  acc.Type = 'Prospect';
  update acc;
}
```

But the problem with the above is that the UI won't show it as **disabled** rather, it spits out an error message.

So for certain profiles (say "Officer") with FLS of "Read-only", I want it such that when I log in as System Admin the combobox will be updateable. **However as that "Officer", the lightning combobox to be disabled like below :**

[image: FLS combobox]

**DisableComboboxExample.html**

> ```
> <td>
>    <lightning-combobox
>      name={index}
>      label="Type"
>      variant="label-hidden"
>      class="label-hidden"
>      data-recid={item.Id}
>      data-id="Type"
>      value={item.xitem.Response__c}
>      options={picklistValuesData}
>      onchange={handleChange}
>      read-only={JS Function logic??}>
>      </lightning-combobox>
> </td>
> ```

**DisableComboboxExample.js**

```
import { LightningElement,track,wire, api } from 'lwc';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';

import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/account';
import ACCOUNT_TYPE from '@salesforce/schema/Account.TYPE';
import ExecuteUpdate from '@salesforce/apex/GetXItems.ExecuteUpdate';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';


export default class DisableComboboxExampleextends LightningElement {
    @track error;
    @track picklistValuesData;

// private
     _recordTypeId;

    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT})
    objectInfo;

    @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId', fieldApiName: Type})

    wiredPicklistValues({data,error}){
        if (data) {
            this.picklistValuesData = data.values;
        } else if (error) {
            console.log('wiredPicklistValues Error-> ', error);
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to code this in Javascript/Apex to expose this on HTML?

===========================================================================
*** 21 OCT 2019 UPDATE ***

Here is the full update example code I'm working with.

**comboboxBasedOnFLS.html**

```
<template>
    <template if:true={TypePicklistValues.data}>
        <lightning-combobox
        label="Disabled Combobox example"
        value={selectedOption}
        options={options}
        disabled={disableAccountEdit} 
        ></lightning-combobox>
    </template>
</template>
```

**comboboxBasedOnFLS.js**

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';
import TYPE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Type';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

const fields = [TYPE_FIELD];

export default class ComboboxBasedOnFLS extends LightningElement {
  @api recordId;
  @track selectedOption;
  @track options;

  // private
  _recordTypeId;

  @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: 
 '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId', fieldApiName: TYPE_FIELD})
 TypePicklistValues;

 // Step 1
 @wire(getRecord, {recordId:'$recordId', fields})
 account({error, data}) {
    if (data) {
      let typeValue = getFieldValue(data, TYPE_FIELD);
      this.selectedOption = typeValue;
      this._recordTypeId = '012000000000000AAA'; 
    } else if (error) {
     // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

 // Step 2, determined by when the reactive bind is changed
  @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '$_recordTypeId', fieldApiName:TYPE_FIELD })
 setPicklistOptions({error, data}) {
   if (data) {
    // Apparently combobox doesn't like it if you dont supply any options at all.
    // Even though selectedOption was assigned in step 1, it wont "select" it unless it also has options
     this.options = data.values;
   } else if (error) {
     // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log(error);
  }
}

 @wire(getPicklistValues, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT })
   accObj;

 get disableAccountEdit() {
   return !this.accObj.data.fields.Type.updateable;
  }

}
```

With this code the whole component won't be visible but if I take away the

> disabled={disableAccountEdit}

, the lwc component will appear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update** How to get Object Describe in Lightning Web Component.
You can get that using the `uiObjectInfoApi` module.

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';

export default class FieldDescribeDemo extends LightningElement {
    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT })
    propertyOrFunction;

    // just to check what info we get.
    get propertyOrFunction1(){
        return JSON.stringify(this.propertyOrFunction);
    }
}
```

See I have stringified the response I am getting from **uiObjectInfoApi**

```
<template>
    {propertyOrFunction1}
</template>
```

Which gave me all of the schema details for an account in [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_responses_object_info.htm#ui_api_responses_object_info) JSON structure.

So basically you can check if the field is editable or not using below syntax.

```
propertyOrFunction.data.fields.<Field-Api-Name>.<createable/updateable>
```

eg: If I want to check if I can edit the AccountNumber field, I will use the below syntax.

```
propertyOrFunction.data.fields.AccountNumber.updateable
```

So using this you can easily disable it using another property/function like below JS code.

```
get disableAccountEdit() {
    return !this.propertyOrFunction.data.fields.AccountNumber.updateable;
}
```

HTML:

```
<lightning-combobox
     name={index}
     label="Type"
     variant="label-hidden"
     class="label-hidden"
     data-recid={item.Id}
     data-id="Type"
     value={item.xitem.Response__c}
     options={picklistValuesData}
     onchange={handleChange}
     disabled={disableAccountEdit}>
</lightning-combobox>
```

[Playground Example to disable input box](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/q-gdVLVtu/2/edit)

---

**Update based on Update in Question**

`objectInfo` was not defined anywhere in your updated code.

See below example, it works fine for me.

```
@wire(getPicklistValues, {
    recordTypeId:
        '$accObj.defaultRecordTypeId', fieldApiName: ACCOUNT_TYPE
})
TypePicklistValues;

@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT })
wiredAccountInfo({ error, data }) {
    console.log('in wiredAcountInfo ' + JSON.stringify(this.data));
    console.log('in wiredAcountInfo ' + JSON.stringify(this.error));
    if (data) {
        console.log('in wiredAcountInfo sucess ' + JSON.stringify(data));
        this.accObj = data;
        this.error = undefined;
    } else if (error) {
        console.log('error > ' + error);
        this.error = error;
        this.accObj = undefined;
    }
}

get disableAccountEdit() {
    if(this.accObj){
        return !this.accObj.fields.Type.updateable;
    }
    return false;
}

get hasPicklistValues() {
    return this.TypePicklistValues && this.TypePicklistValues.data && this.TypePicklistValues.data.values;
}
```

HTML

```
<template>
    <template if:true={hasPicklistValues}>
        <lightning-combobox label="Disabled Combobox example" value={selectedOption} options={TypePicklistValues.data.values}
            disabled={disableAccountEdit}></lightning-combobox>
    </template>
</template>
```

Comment: What is the equivalent of  !Schema.SObjectType.Account.fields.Type.isUpdateable() of apex into js?

Comment: @compski you can get that in `uiObjectInfoApi` see I have updated my answer

Comment: nice! answer is alot better. However, I noticed one thing though, if updateable = true, then disabled = true (which means the combobox will be disabled even though the FLS is true), and I cannot use Expression Functions on html to do "!propertyOrFunction.data.fields.AccountNumber.updateable". How to get around this?

Comment: @Compski ohh thats a good catch.. let me update it in answer

Comment: I tried putting your changes in -> "return !this.propertyOrFunction.data.fields.AccountNumber.updateable;" but it still does not disable the combobox when I login as a user with read-only to that field (Even when the object and field is read-only )

Comment: please update your question and add the code you have tried

Comment: hey Rahul, have updated my question, use the comboboxBasedOnFLS LWC example. The disable function you told me to add on JS page doesn't work for me.

Comment: @compski I have updated the working code in the last section of the answer.

Comment: It finally works now - surprised you didn't use any track, api annotations for it

Comment: Yeah, they are not needed always.